# A ball in bag and biased coin flip problem

Tags: probability

Given a bag of $m$ white balls and $n$ black balls, pick balls at random without replacement and flip a coin each time. If the ball is white the coin lands heads with probability $p$, if the ball is black the coin lands heads with probability $q$. What is the probability that the first head is on a white ball, given that at least one coin of either colour lands heads?

The probability that at least one coin of either colour lands heads is $1-(1-p)^m(1-q)^n$.

Sadly I can't figure out the rest of it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean to choose balls without replacement?  In that case, of course, it is possible that we never see Heads from a coin.

Comment: Yes, without replacement. The probability I'm looking for is a conditional probability, conditional on the event that at least one coin does land heads.

Comment: I am not sure this has a pleasant solution. There's a recursion of course...after the first ball is drawn then either you are done or you are in a case with one fewer ball.  That should make it easy to compute lots of values and you can see if that suggests a possible analytic form.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Also, it seems like it would be identical to this problem: You have a bag of $m$ $p$-coins, and $n$ $q$-coins.  You draw coins (which look and feel identical) without replacement and flip them one at a time; given that at least one comes up heads, what's the probability that the first one is a $p$-coin?